# Custom property is empty

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have custom action which stores the file location into property at immediate phase.
Then I have another action at deffered phase, which reads this property and creates the file:

```
String configFilePath = session.CustomActionData["configPath"];
String configFileName = session.CustomActionData["configFile"];
...
```

Everything works so far.
At uninstall I would like to remove this file, so I have another deffered action, which executes after removing files. Action works, the problem is that property is empty(session.CustomActionData is empty).
Why? I have setted it at immediate phase also when uninstall is happening. And if I can read it at custom setUpConfig action, why I can't read it at custom removeConfig action?
I guess one option is to store this value into registry at installing phase and then read it from there when uninstalling. But I would like to know why i can set the property when installing the program, and why it is not setted at uninstalling. The action, which sets the proeprty is executed in both cases.

```
<CustomAction Id="ConfigFileLocation" Property="setUpConfig" Execute="immediate" 
Value="configPath=[WEBSITE];configFile=config_template.asp" />

<CustomAction Id="setUpConfig" BinaryKey="MyCustomAction" DllEntry="configFile"  
Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"  Return="check" />

<CustomAction Id="removeConfig" BinaryKey="MyCustomAction"  
DllEntry="removeCustomFile"  Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"  Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="ConfigFileLocation" After="LaunchConditions" />
<Custom Action="setUpConfig" Before="InstallFinalize"><![CDATA[NOT REMOVE="ALL"]] />
<Custom Action="removeConfig" After="RemoveFiles"><![CDATA[REMOVE="ALL"]] />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass data to a deferred custom action you must set a `Property` with a name that matches the `CustomAction/@Id`.  You are doing that correctly for the `setUpConfig` custom action via the immediate `ConfigFileLocation` custom action.

However, the `removeConfig` custom action does not have an immediate custom action setting a `Property` named `removeConfig`.

Ergo the `removeConfig` custom action's `CustomActionData` property is blank.

Comment: Thanks, it works now.
If I write my properties to registry with RegistryValue and read them with RegistrySearch to some property, do I still have to create immediate custom actions to pass data to my custom uninstall action or is it better to read the registry values directly from my custom uninstall action inside c#? Or is there some other propossed way?

Comment: You only need to set the `Property` with the same name as the custom action. You could have a `RegistrySearch` set the `Property` directly if you wanted and that works for you.